# FreeBSD bootloader won't boot from the correct pool

Tags: boot, freebsd, boot-loader, zfs

I've installed FreeBSD 10.1 on a system which has two ZFS pools, and which boots from an other hard disk, which contains only the bootloader. The main pool disks are connected to SATA ports on a PCI-E card, while the bootloader tries to boot from the wrong pool (the second pool, which is connected directly to the SATA ports on the motherboard).

The error is the following:

```
Can't find /boot/zfsloader
FreeBSD/x86 boot
Default: storage:/boot/kernel/kernel
boot:
/
Cant't find /boot/kernel/kernel
FreeBSD/x86 boot
Default: storage:/boot/kernel/kernel
boot:
```

I tried to set vfs.root.mountfrom="zfs:zpool" or "zfs:zpool/ROOT" in /mnt/boot/loader.conf but it doesn't work.

If I unplug the disks of the second pool, the system boots up correctly.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured that out by myself.

ZFS Loader doesn't allow to set a root pool to boot from, but it tries to guess the correct one by pooling the BIOS for the boot priority order.

To make it boot from the correct pool, I set as first booting device in the BIOS the drive containing the bootloader, and as second and third the drives belonging to the root mirrored pool.

Answer (score 0):

try to `cp -r /boot` from correct pool to wrong pool. ensure that `bootfs` property on wrong pool is empty or set to correct pool.

Comment: could you clarify your commands a little better, using details from original post, it would make your answer better. tks

Answer (score 0):

Boot from an approriate distribution CD into "live CD" mode.
Log in as root.

Now, let's say your bootable pool is called "tank";

import the pool without mounting it -

```
zpool import -N -f tank
```

Then set the bootfs property approriately.  A common boot
filesystem name is "tank/ROOT/default";

```
zpool set bootfs=tank/ROOT/default tank
```

that's it for the bootable pool.  Repeat for the non-bootable pool,
this time setting the bootfs property to "".  There, you're done.